# Select options not loading when using callback function

Tags: 6

I am creating the select box form element as following

```
$form['select-user-group'] = array(
       '#type' => 'select',
       '#title' => t('Select a group'),
       '#options' => select_user_dropdown_options(),      
       '#description' => t('Select a group to send the mail.'))
```

and am trying load the options for select box like follwing

```
function select_user_dropdown_options(){
    db_set_active('drupal');
    $result = db_query("select * from {content_type_usergroup}");   
    $record = db_fetch_object($result);
    $str = '<select><option>-- Select a user group--</option>';
    while ($obj = db_fetch_object($result)) {
        $str .= '<option>'+$obj->field_p_group_name_value+'</option>';
     }
     $str .='</select>';
     return $str;
}
```

> But its not loading options to the select box , please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call back function should be like follows :

```
function select_user_dropdown_options(){
    db_set_active('drupal');
    $result = db_query('select * from {users}');
    $options = array();
    $options[] = '-- Select a user  --';
    while ($row = db_fetch_object($result)) {
      $options[$row->uid] = $row->name;
    }
     return $options;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your select_user_dropdown_options() function needs to return an array of options, not a block of HTML. See the [#options section](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#options) of the Form API documentation -- you should find yourself re-reading that Form API page a lot.

Your array will be in the form

```
array(
  'group_1' => 'Group 1',
  'group_2' => 'Group 2',
);
```

A pedantic note -- I believe that's really a function call as opposed to a callback. That's fine; I mention it mostly because you don't include the parentheses when providing the names of callback functions.

Comment: thank you , but am getting like options load like along with optgroup

Comment: now am getting it like this : <select name="select-user" class="form-select" id="edit-select-user"><optgroup label="0"><option value="0">-- Select a user  --</option></optgroup><optgroup label="1"><option value="0">vmadmin</option></optgroup><optgroup label="2"><option value="0">auto</option></optgroup><optgroup label="3"><option value="0">mnc</option></optgroup></select>   how can i remove opt group ?

Comment: Did my answer address your original question or is that still unresolved?

Comment: Its actually solved some how , i was returning a string insted of array , thanks

Comment: Yeah, returning an array -- in that form -- was crucial. The Form API page gives a lot more detail and is very helpful.

Would you mind marking this as a successful answer, please?